# How can I mock an instance variable returned from a Client in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, instance-variables

I have a service client that I call which returns a bunch of instance variables. I call this in a method which is called inside another method to return a response

I want my method to return a specific one like so

```
def returnsAlias
  model = ClientGem.find(id) #finds a bunch of instance variables by id
  model.alias #returns @alias
end
```

In my spec I have

```
allow(ClientGem).to receive(:find).and_return('Test Alias')
```

I'm not sure what to replace 'Test Alias' with. I tried @alias and using

```
@alias.instance_variable_set(:@alias, 'Test Alias')
```

But this returns this error

```
FrozenError:
   can't modify frozen NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stub out the object itself.

```
model = instance_double(ClientGemReturnedKlass, alias: 'Test Alias')
allow(ClientGem).to receive(:find).and_return(model)
```

Comment: Hmm. I get an error
           `the ClientGem::Model class does not implement the instance method: alias`

Comment: you're calling `model.alias` in your code so I assume the class returned from `ClienGem.find(id)` is something else

Comment: `.find(id)` returns a bunch of instance variables, one of which I can access with `.alias`

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense, no function call returns instance variables, they return objects.  What object is returned from `ClientGem.find(id)`?  If you do `ClientGem.find(id).class`, what is returned?

Comment: Ah thank you. The documentation for the gem is confusing. They use `.class` to return the objects but they have instance variables in the documentation.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯